# How does opengl knows how many vertex there are?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently trying to learn opengl and in doing so, I ran into a question that needs clarifcation. So basically, I was told that vertex shader applies to every vertex once. I am not so sure how does it know how many data constitutes to a vertex because all that I am giving the shader is basically a buffer containing a bunch of floats.

Consider the following code:

```
GLuint vbo = 0;
glGenBuffer(1, &vbo); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,7 * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,3*3*sizeof(GLfloat),vertices);
glSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,3*3*sizeof(GLfloat),4*3*sizeof(GLfloat),colors);
GLuint pos = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "position");
GLuint col = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "color");
glVertexAttribPointer(pos,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
glVertexAttribPointer(col,4,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,3*3*sizeof(GLfloat));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(col);
glUseProgram(programId);
glDrawArray(GL_TRIANGLE,0,3);
```

This is just to draw a simple triangle and so the shader is just declaring gl_position and an output color on the fragment shader. Please consider that my vertex shader will have a variable called position and my fragment shader has a variable called color.

Now, the problem that I don't understand is I never specify an ending point for my vertex in the vbo. As a result, how does opengl knows that it should only look at the first 9 float position in the vbo and not go over to the color rgba specification in the vbo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two answers to your question:

- In your special case, you tell OpenGL how many vertices to draw in your last line: [`glDrawArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) takes `count` as its third argument which, when you are not using index buffers, is exactly the number of vertices that will be drawn.
  Because you chose `GL_TRIANGLE` as your primitive type, 3 consecutive vertices will be drawn as a single vertex.
- If you use an index buffer, you specify the number of *indices* you want to render, i.e. how many entries of the index buffer should be used for drawing. The maximum number in the index buffer in turn tells OpenGL how many vertices will be used at most.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. So just a quick clarification, I specify 3 in the glDrawArray but how does it knows what data type it is? How does it knows to pull 3 floats at a time since my data is basically a vec3f?  Now I have thought of the case where glVertexAttribPointer could be use to tell it to pull 3 floats at a time for each vertex but the problem is that how does it knows to use the glVertextAttribPointer for position rather than for glVertexAttribPointer for color in my code above?

Comment: This is part of the [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) parameters:
You specify that every entry of the `pos` buffer will consist of 3 floats and every entry of the `col` buffer will consist of 4 floats.

Comment: But I am not quite sure why would it knows to use the pos entry instead of the col entry when querying for floats.

Comment: Aah, now I understand your question correctly. This is due to the last argument of glVertexAttribPointer: It provides the *offset* GL uses to look for the entries for this vertex attribute. So the layout of your buffer is
`| vertices | colors |` and thus you need to tell GL where the vertices and colors sections start, which you do in your call by specifying the offsets `0` and `3*3*sizeof(GLfloat)`, which is exactly the amount of space you need to skip the vertices and get to the colors directly.

Comment: Oh ok this makes a lot more sense now. So basically the glDrawArray matches the offset to those in the glAttribPointer correct? So if I have it as offset of 3*3*sizeof(GLfloat) it would query 4 float instead of 3 right?